# Insert a DateObject into MySQL database?

Tags: databaselink, sql, jdbc

I want to use Mathematica to do some SQL tasks like insert. However, I have difficulty in inserting date into SQL. Here is an example.

```
conn = OpenSQLConnection[
  JDBC["MySQL(Connector/J)", "localhost:3306/dbTest"], 
  "Name" -> "dbTest", "Username" -> "mathematica", 
  "Password" -> "password"]

SQLInsert[conn, SQLTable["match"], {"id", "time", "home_id"}, {1, Now, 100}]
```

I got the following error:

```
JDBC::error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match (id,season,league_id,time,home_id,away_id,fthg,ftag,hthg,htag) VALUES (1,2' at line 1
```

I think it's probably because of the date object. I also converted the `DateObject` into `DateString`, the same happens.

```
SQLInsert[conn, SQLTable["match"], {"id", "time", "home_id"}, 
{1, DateString[Now, {"ISODate", " ", "Time", ".", "Millisecond", "000"}], 100}]

JDBC::error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match (id,season,league_id,time,home_id,away_id,fthg,ftag,hthg,htag) VALUES (1,2' at line 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you are on the right track with ````DateString````.

It returns something like ````"2019-02-01 10:00:35.952000"````
Are all of those characters legal in your table?

Comment: @RudyPotter you are right here with the approach `DateString`. As it turns out, the `DateObject` was not the only problem. See my own answer below.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that inserting `DateObject`s should be possible, as long as the column type allows for it. I've definitely done that in the past. It might depend on the database and the connector, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`SQLDateTime`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/DatabaseLink/ref/SQLDateTime.html) with [`DateList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateList.html).

```
SQLInsert[conn, 
  SQLTable["match"], 
  {"id", "time", "home_id"}, 
  {1, SQLDateTime@DateList[], 100}
]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, `DateObject` is not the only problem here. I kind of lack in some basic knowledge in SQL. Here are the mistakes I made.

1. `DateObject` cannot be passed to SQL. `DateString[Now, "ISODate"]` was a right approach.
2. I shouldn't name my table `match`, because it is in conflict with the SQL command.
3. Column name `as` is also not allowed. Same reason here.